# Unit test html element with ngif async call in angular 2 jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, ngrx, angular-test

I am writing unit test for html div having a `*ngIf` condition.

```
<div *ngIf="clientSearchResults$ | async  as searchResults" class = 'fgf'  #datalist id="mydata" >
  <app-client-list id="clientDataTable1" class="clientDataTable dataTable" [clients]='searchResults'></app-client-list>
</div>
```

This `ngIf` condition gets true, when I recieved the data from [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) store. Below is the component code, which filled this data.

```
searchData(client: Client) {
      //// some conditions
      this._clientService.getClientList()
     .subscribe(data => {
      const filteredData = this.filterData(data, client);
      this.isDataFound = filteredData !== null && filteredData.length > 0;
      this.testbool = true;
      /// In this line, my div got the data and using async condition, we 
      /// fill the div element.
      this.store.dispatch(new SetClientSearchResultsAction(filteredData));

    });
}
```

Now, when writing the unit test case for this.

```
it('should search the data with valid client passed from UI', async(() => {
    let debugFixture: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    let htmlElement: HTMLElement = debugFixture.nativeElement;
    let clientListGrid = htmlElement.getElementsByClassName('fgf');
    let testbool= htmlElement.getElementsByClassName('testbool');

    spyOn(component, 'searchData').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'filterData').and.returnValue(CLIENT_OBJECT);
    spyOn(clientService, 'getClientList').and.callThrough();

    console.log("=========before======="+ clientListGrid.length);

    component.searchData(validClient);
    component.clientSearchResults$ = store.select('searchResults');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    debugFixture = fixture.debugElement;
    htmlElement = debugFixture.nativeElement;
    clientListGrid = htmlElement.getElementsByClassName('fgf');

    console.log("=========after ======="+ clientListGrid.length);

    expect(component.searchData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Problem is, in console, before calling the function, I am getting the length as 0 and after calling the function also, I am getting the length as 0. It should be 1, When We have received the data from store.
And It is just because of this *ngif condition, `*ngIf="clientSearchResults$ | async  as searchResults"`

Data is getting load in DIV, but still, in unit test I am not able to test this thing ?

Comment: Have you tried to use ``query(By.css('.fgf'))`` or ``query(By.css('.testbool'))`` ? are you sure that ``clientListGrid`` or ``testbool`` have the right content ?

Comment: yes, I have test that thing, TestBool css is on another div, it was just for testing purpose with simple ngif ( no async), and it is working correctly.

Comment: Try to debug your test using chrome, you can then add some details about the lines of code you think are not giving the results, or try to create a demo with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-grhfjo?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)

Comment: In the component file, every line is running correctly, In HTML file, from unit testing when I am trying to access that particular div, that is not having any data. 
`clientListGrid = htmlElement.getElementsByClassName('fgf');
console.log("=========after ======="+ clientListGrid.length);`
this should give some correct data. length as 1 when data has been loaded

Comment: yes, already debug, all lines are running correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167992/discussion-between-nimish-goel-and-hdjemai).

Comment: Hi have you found any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I know I’m too late but somebody might read it in future so.

I had the same problem and it was because of bug in Angular testing that it doesn’t trigger change detection when passed new value to input if the components `ChangeDetectionStrategy` is `OnPush`

So what you need to do is override it in Testing module:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ... your declarations and providers
})
.overrideComponent(ComponentYoureTesting, {
  set: { changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default }
})
.compileComponents();
```

And it should work

Answer (score 2):

Probably this can help:

```
it('should search the data with valid client passed from UI', fakeAsync(() => {
  // ---
  tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // --- 
  expect(component.searchData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: Nop, That thing I have already tried, have tried use of `done` as well.